# iterating through matrix is slower when changing A[i][j] to A[j][i]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance, caching

I have a matrix of `int`s named `A`, and when I'm iterating trough it by columns instead of rows, it runs about 50 ms slower:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)  
        cout<<A[j][i];    //slower than of A[i][j]
```

Does anyone know why does this happen? I've asked a couple of people, but none of them knew **why**. I'm sure it's related to how the addresses are represented in computer's memory, but still, I'd like to find a more concrete answer.

Comment: can you post the code where you initialize the array?

Comment: it's a global array, it's just `int A[100][100]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterating through the matrix row by row is faster because of ***cache memory***.

When you access `A[i][j]`, there is more memory being loaded into the cache than just one element. Note that each row of your matrix is stored within continuous memory block, thus when *the memory "around"* `A[i][j]` is still in cache, it is more probable that accessing next element within the same row will result in it being read from cache rather than main memory (see *[cache miss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_miss#Cache_miss)*).

Also see related questions:
[Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9936132/1168156)
[Which of these two for loops is more efficient in terms of time and cache performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9888154/1168156)
[How cache memory works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218117/1168156)
[Matrix multiplication: Small difference in matrix size, large difference in timings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7905760/1168156)

Answer (score 3):

A **2D array is stored in memory as a 1D array**, in (row/column) major. What this means is that an array with 5 columns, might be stored as 5 columns one after the other, so based on how you access vs this ordering, **your accesses might be cached, or every one of them might cause cache fails**, causing the large difference in performance.

Answer (score 3):

It's about cache line read mechanism.
Read about [spatial locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Use_of_spatial_and_temporal_locality%3a_hierarchical_memory).

To verify, try to disable cache while running this application. (I forgot how to do this, but it can be done.)

Answer (score 3):

AS others have noted, it is a cache issue. Using it one way may cause a cache miss each time an array element is accessed.

The cache issue is actually a very important factor for optimizations. It's the reason why it is sometimes better to do a structure of arrays instead of array of structures. Compare these two:

```
struct StructOfArrays {
  int values[100];
  char names[100][100];
}

struct StructOfArrays values;

struct NormalValStruct {
  int val;
  char name[100];
}

struct NormalValStruct values[100];
```

If you iterate over values in `StructOfArrays` they will be probably loaded into cache and read efficiently. When you iterate over `NormalValStruct` and get the value member, you will get a cache miss every other time.

That trick is often used in high-performance applications. Which are, often, games.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first loop accesses memory linear the other with gaps in between. Thus the first loop is friendlier for the cache.