# Is it a good practice to put independent methods under a loop or separate loops?

Tags: c#

for example

```
  for (int i=1;i<10000;i++)
  {
       j++;
       k++;
  }
```

or

```
  for (int i=1;i<10000;i++)
  {
       j++;
  }
  for (int i=1;i<10000;i++)
  {
       k++;
  }
```

Note 1: in c# is it still better to use `++i` instead of `i++`?

Note 2: A good thing that if we spilt a large loop into separate simple loops is that then we can transform it into Linq form, such as `enumerable.range(1,10000).forall(x=>j++)` so in the lambda expression or delegate i don't have to put multiple statements together.

Comment: When have you heard it better to use ++i over i++? It should make no difference...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145389/for-loop-mechanism-efficiency-tips here

Comment: In this case I would assume a single loop is more efficient as you are only incrementing i 9999 times as opposed to 19998 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) almost the same

(2) Use one loop if the code in the loop is quite simple, like `i++` or `j++`. Note that using separate loops for 2 complex methods is probably faster than one loop:

```
//better and faster
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    OneThing(i);
}
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    AnotherThing(i);
}
```

Separated loops improves the hit rate of the registers. If you put them in one loop, the time reduced by 1000 loops is less than the more time cost by register miss.

Answer (score 4):

1: no difference in performance; if you are using it *as part of an expression* it simply gives you the flexibility to use either form

2: LINQ gains you little here; you're still *ultimately* doing the same loop (unless you switch to `Parallel`, in which case your `++` is broken) - but if you add LINQ you're adding overheads to do it.

re how many loops; in this case I'd do one loop - but define it logically in terms of the bounds etc. Unless either of the operations is complex, in which case maybe split that out to a separate method.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think the question is about performance - it's .NET after all! so don't worry about optimisation - isn't the question about programming STYLE? i.e. Which form is best for readability, refactorisation, compatibility, robustness etc?

Comment: @Sanjay " it's .NET after all! so don't worry about optimisation " - trolling much?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: the compiler takes care of that for you, and whether it is better depends on the usage as the behaviour is slightly different.  I think the compiler emits `++i` in the case of `for` loops, but for `for` loops it also makes no difference.

To answer your second question: there is no concept of best practice in this case.  Your lambda can do more than one action anyway.  **Write the code that is easiest to understand and maintain.**

Answer (score 0):

The same concept of post and pre increment holds good in c# as well.

And seperating into multiple loops as you ahve shown shall create more over head coz now your iterating twice than once before.

Comment: But the compiler should optimize that out for you.

Comment: I highly doubt if it optimize 2 loops into 1. What if in a code i want literally 2 loops for different puropose? if compiler merges, then my results shall be different right.

Comment: You're right, checked using ildasm. Thought it might branch predict it out, since there isn't really anything going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use the approach that is easier to read and understand.